# Tags from mysql

Tags: mysql

I was made code which return rows with similar tags from "tagi"(that is column name).

My code:

require("connmysql.php");

```
if ($f == "podobne") {

    $kategorieProgramu = $string;
    $kategorieProgramu = explode(', ', $kategorieProgramu);

    $sql = 'SELECT odc_ListaAnime';
    $ifs = [];
    foreach ($kategorieProgramu as $kategoria) {
        $ifs[] = "IF (gatunek LIKE '%" . trim($kategoria) . "%', 1, 0)";
    }

    $sql .= implode('+', $ifs) . 'AS gatunek';

    $sql .= " FROM odc_ListaAnime HAVING gatunek > 0 ORDER BY gatunek DESC LIMIT 3";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $maxodc = $row['maxodc'];
            $anime = $row['nazwa'];
            if(getLA("lodc", $anime) == $maxodc){
            }else{
                echo "- <a href='index.php?str=anime&anime=$anime'>$anime</a><br>";
            }
        }
    } else {
         echo "<h1> ERROR 404 </h1>";
    }
    $conn->close();

}
```

but that code isnt work fine... I get error message:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/chumorekgn/www/maneku/get.php on line 301
ERROR 404

301 line is

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

when i was add var_dump to $sql

i got

string(173) "SELECT odc_ListaAnime;IF (gatunek LIKE '%Komedia%', 1, 0)+IF (gatunek LIKE '%Romans%', 1, 0)AS gatunekFROM odc_ListaAnime HAVING gatunek > 0 ORDER BY gatunek DESC LIMIT 3"

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's mysql, so use ',' to separate columns instead ';' in your query:

```
"SELECT odc_ListaAnime, IF...
```

Also you need to implement some catching of pdo errors to see real SQL errors.

Add this wrapper:

```
  if ($result) {
      $result->num_rows > 0) {
          ...
      }
  } else {
      echo 'database error: '.$conn->errorInfo(); die;
  }
```

Comment: SELECT odc_ListaAnime,IF (gatunek LIKE '%Dramat%', 1, 0)+IF (gatunek LIKE '%Komedia%', 1, 0)+IF (gatunek LIKE '%Romans%', 1, 0)AS gatunek; HAVING gatunek > 0 ORDER BY gatunek DESC LIMIT 3

Doesnt work

Comment: Where is your FROM part? Query must be "SELECT odc_ListaAnime, IF (gatunek LIKE '%Komedia%', 1, 0)+IF (gatunek LIKE '%Romans%', 1, 0) AS gatunek FROM odc_ListaAnime HAVING gatunek > 0 ORDER BY gatunek DESC LIMIT 3"

Comment: Okey, i forget about it but it still doesnt work

"SELECT odc_ListaAnime, IF (gatunek LIKE '%Dramat%', 1, 0)+IF (gatunek LIKE '%Komedia%', 1, 0)+IF (gatunek LIKE '%Romans%', 1, 0) AS gatunek FROM odc_ListaAnime HAVING gatunek > 0 ORDER BY gatunek DESC LIMIT 3"

Comment: query is correct, add error catching in your code (I updated my answer)

Comment: Query syntax is correct, but may be some errors are in naming or in other places. Let database help you to define mistake and execute this query directly in mysql console or phpMyAdmin or elsewhere and see the result. Or add debugging if-else to your app as I wrote in answer.